# How to stop firebase in android from automatically verifying email when authenticating with google

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I currently have two methods for creating a user account using FirebaseUI, these are EmailAndPassword and Google's option.

When utilizing the Email and Password way the account is not automatically verified but when doing it with google it gets automatically verified... Is there a way to prevent google from doing this?

All the code I use is provided by Firebase's documentation and I didn't find anything about this specific issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to prevent google from doing this?

No.  When you choose to use an auth provider other than Firebase Auth's own email/password, you are **implicitly** trusting that provider to have already validated that user.  With Google, the account's email address is provided by Google itself (via gmail, obviously), so no email verification needs to be done.  Google has other ways of validating the user account in ways that don't necessarily involve email.

If you don't trust Google's validation of the user, then don't use them as an auth provider.

Comment: I see, It's kind of a bummer that it's done that way but I do understand why it is that way. I'll have to find another method of verifying a google email